# Printing multiple tables together in Python

Tags: python, numpy, printing, tabular

I've got this code:

```
import numpy as np

headings = np.array(["userID","name","bookingID"])
data = np.array([[1111111,"Joe Bloggs",2222222][1212121,"Jane Doe",3333333]])
```

How do I go about printing this data in this way:

```
userID
1111111
name
Joe Bloggs
bookingID
2222222
userID
1212121
name
Jane Doe
bookingID
3333333
```

This is the closest I've gotten...

```
keys = headings.values
datas = df.values
for i in datas:
    for j in keys:
        print(j)
        print(i)
```

---

results:

```
userID
[1111111 'Joe Bloggs' 2222222]
name
[1111111 'Joe Bloggs' 2222222]
bookingID
[1111111 'Joe Bloggs' 2222222]
userID
[1212121 'Jane Doe' 3333333]
name
[1212121 'Jane Doe' 3333333]
bookingID
[1212121 'Jane Doe' 3333333]
```

But I'm struggling with the extra step to narrow it to the specific data for each key... can somebody help? (Also can somebody recommend a better question title?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

headings = np.array(["userID","name","bookingID"])
data = np.array([[1111111,"Joe Bloggs",2222222],[1212121,"Jane Doe",3333333]])


for sublist in data: #iterate through data
    for ind, value in enumerate(sublist): #iterate through each sublist  and remember index
        print(headings[ind]) #print the element in headings that corresponds to index
        print(value) #print the element
```

Output:

```
>>>userID
>>>1111111
>>>name
>>>Joe Bloggs
>>>bookingID
>>>2222222
>>>userID
>>>1212121
>>>name
>>>Jane Doe
>>>bookingID
>>>3333333
```

Comment: glad I could help :)